# There is a way to know if other application is using a sensor [Android]

Tags: android, android-sensors, sensormanager

I´m working in a POC in Android and I need to know if another application is using a sensor (moreover if it is starting or shutting down a sensor).

Do you know if SensorManager does that?

Perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: Generally this sort of thing is not supported for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks for your repply. Thats exactly why I need to know if someone else are using a sensor. I just need to know if a sensor is being started or stopped.